# dynamic modify DOM with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new with angularjs and I am trying to add some dynamic content to the DOM.
What I want to do is a little bit like twitter for example.
I have a table with different rows and if the user click on a row, there is some details ajax loaded just ender the row.
I have a template for the row details (which I want to display (and compile) just ender the clicked row.
As I don't realy understand how to trigger a directive with click, I have tried to do it from a controller function (with ng-click on the row) but I can't compile (I only have the template displaying).

If anyone has an idea how to do it (and best, a way to do it with directive as it seems to be the right way to do it).

Thanks

Comment: Try to create a plunker http://plnkr.co.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not clear how complicated your template is that you want to add, you may not need a directive — ng-repeat on the <tr> element may be enough.  On the AngularJS home page, the "Wire up a Backend" demo, tab list.html shows how to dynamically add rows to a table using ng-repeat, with data that was retrieved via the query() method.  Is this sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Well, the template I want to add is not that compilcated but it has a list, some details about the messages and items of the list and a form to add new comments.
Here is how I would like it to work
http://jsfiddle.net/tagazok/gHvJr/2/
(I haven't put the template but the idea is to load the template dynamicaly ender the clicked row.

Comment: I think you should use nested div's instead of tr's, that way you could have nested ng-repeats.  The outter ng-repeat would be for the messages, and the inner ng-repeat would be for the comments associated with a message.  Put all the data into the same $scope object.  E.g., $scope.messages = [ { id: '1', text:'t1', date:'...', comments: [] }, {...}, ...].  Have your ng-click handler add the comments to the appropriate entry in array $scope.messages and Angular should automatically update the view for you.